# Assiging an integer pointer to array of structures and still code getting executed?

Tags: c, pointers

I saw the following fragment of C code in a text book and it's working properly... But I do not understand the output and why is it working properly, because it looks wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    struct {
        int x,y;
    } s[4] = {{10,20},{15,25},{8,75},{6,2}};
    int *i;
    i=s;

    clrscr();
    printf("\n%d",s[i[7]].x);
    printf("\n%d",i[i[1]-i[2]]);
    printf("\n%d",i[s[3].y]);
    printf("\n%d",(s+1)->x+5);
    printf("\n%d",s[i[0]-i[4]].y + 10);
    printf("\n%d",++i[i[6]]);
    getch();

    return 0;

}
```

Also I do not understand how we can assign an integer pointer to `s` in the statement

```
i=s;
```

Comment: Which line are you concerned about?

Comment: Also, this code doesn't compile.  See e.g. http://ideone.com/7pTKA.

Comment: The first two printf statements..I Dont understand how they mean.

Comment: Maybe ideone uses gcc.But it does get compiled on TC

Comment: If we remove getch() for gcc then it would compile

Comment: Then you need to turn your compiler's warning level up.  This code is invalid.

Comment: Works on codepad, too, after removing clrscr and getch http://codepad.org/bqEzZd2p.  Agree with Oli Charlesworth that the code is terrible, but weak typing in general is terrible.  -Wall FTW!

Comment: What is the name of the book so we can steer clear of it?

Comment: @ouah: The textbook this code snippet is from could of very well been explaining the compatibility of pointer types as well as memory layout.

Comment: this was a sample question in Let Us C from Yashwant Kanitkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the pointer assignment:

To take a comment from below:

> "the memory layout of an array of ints and an array of struct composed
>   solely by ints is the same"

The reason pointer types must be defined are because the compiler must know the **size** of the data the pointer is **pointing to**. Integers have a size of 4 byes, while this struct would have a size of 8 bytes. When the program tries to access the memory at location `s[1]`, the compiler knows that the program wants the data 8 bytes after `s[0]`, where `i[1]` would want the data only 4 bytes after `i[0]`.

`s` is an array of structs(with two members of type int), `i` is a pointer to an int. Since the first element of `s` is a struct of 2 ints, `i = s` assigns the address of the first member of the first element of `s` to `i`.

`i = &s[0]` is the same assignment.

If `s[0]` started at *0x00*, it's first member has the address *0x00*, while it's second member has the address *0x04*. `s[1]` would start at *0x08*, the struct at that location has a  second member with the address *0x0C*.

With `i = s`, `i[0]` has the address *0x00*, while `i[1]` has the address *0x04*, the second member of the first element of `s`. `i[2]` has the address *0x08*, the first member of the second struct in the array, `i[3]` has the address *0x0C*, the second member of the second struct in the array. And so on...

```
  { 10, 20 } { 15, 25 } { 8, 75 } { 6, 2 }
s:|    0    |     1    |    2    |   3   |
i:| 0 |  1  |  2 |  3  |  4 | 5  | 6 | 7 |
```

`i` now points at the first integer (out of all 8).

`i[0] = 10`

`i[7] = 2`

The first printf statement is interpreted as follows: Since `i[7] = 2`, then we have `s[2]` referring to the pair `{8,75}`, that has the x value `8`.

The pointers indeed are incompatible, compiling with gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) produces the following ***warning***:

> test.c: In function ‘main’: test.c:10: warning: assignment from
>   incompatible pointer type

However, the program does compile and product the output:

> 8 75 15 20 85

Comment: also wouldn't s be an array of structures?

Comment: @arpitsolanski: for C there's no difference

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: i contains the value of the pointer of the first memory location of s. So yes, it's a pointer to a struct!

Comment: @vanDarg if i[0]=10 and 1[7]=2 then how do you explain the output of first printf?

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio the problem is `i` is declared this way: `int *i;`

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio: Not as far as the compiler/language is concerned.

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio `i` is a pointer to an `int` and you are assigning a pointer to a structure type! This is invalid, there is no implicit conversion between both types.

Comment: @arpitsolanki: Since `i[7] = 2`, then we have `s[2]` referring to the pair `{8,75}`, with the x value `8`.

Comment: @ouah and indeed it raises a warning. Nontheless, the memory layout of  an array of ints and an array of struct composed solely by ints is the same.

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio: Not necessarily.  The structs could be padded.  And even if they weren't, this still violates [strict aliasing rules](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html).

Comment: even before being UB the code is invalid because it violates the constraints of the assignment operator (constraints of the assignment apply in a scalar initialization)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: it this particular case, with a two ints struct, padding is not present, indeed the result is correct. An hack, but correct (at least on my GCC, screaming warning but going on nonetheless apart from the getch() call). And about the aliasing rules, the question was just about why it was possible doing that assingment and still having the correct output.

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio: With this particular compiler for this particular platform, indeed, there is no padding.  But there's no guarantee of that in general.

Comment: Commenting out the getch() and clrscr() calls gcc generates an `incompatible pointer type` warning but still compiles. The program does execute and produce expected output.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Absolutely, but the I believe the question was asking about this struct in particular.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yep the question indeed may refers to different topics: how is c storing data structures and how c treats type conversions. We were simply talking about two different things. Blame the asker ;D

Answer (score 2):

> Also i do not understand how we can assign an integer pointer to s in the statement: `i=s;`

It is simple, you can't in C without a cast. You compiler is kind enough to accept such a program but other compilers have the right to refuse to compile the program.

Comment: But in such a condition shouldn't i be getting a garbage output?

Comment: Each printf above prints some or other element of array

Comment: @arpitsolanki: This code does not compile cleanly in GCC, and that is the problem.

Comment: @ouah: This one's so basic, you don't even need `-Wall`!

Comment: @arpitsolanki: Any behaviour you're observing is **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth even worst;)

Comment: @OLi the code compiles in gcc if we remove getch and clrscr http://ideone.com/TY9jQ

Comment: @arpitsolanki: It doesn't compile cleanly.  ideone.com just isn't showing you the compiler warnings.  Try it at the command-line.

Comment: Yeah i do get the warnings as well when i try it on my gcc,but if the pointer assignment is not right...then why am i not getting garbage as  output and getting elements of s as output???

Comment: @arpitsolanki: Like I said, **undefined behaviour**.  That doesn't mean "crash" or "garbage".

Answer (score 1):

Adding a little : in C I follows the trick when its comes situation like this : whenever you see like this #type# s[p], s is a pointer of #type# type, and s[p] is another way of writing *(s+p). Hence ('i' assigned the base address of the array) for example -- i[i[1]-i[2]] is i[(*(i+1)) - (*(i+2))] => i[20 - 15] => i[5] => *(i+5) => 75.

Also note,

1) Internal padding may be used in allocating storage for struct. for ex. a struct with two ints and one char is not necessarily will take 4+4+2 = 10 bytes consecutively, there may be internal padding. However this struct with two ints only doesn't use internal padding.

2) Warning will be given as incompatible pointer is assigned by most compilers.

3)'i' was alloted the base address of array of structures with no internal padding, thus this carefully designed code magically works.

Comment: Can you throw some light on the internal padding of structures..exactly what is it?

Comment: since computer reads/writes to memory addresses in word sized chunks, so structures having different data types may need internal padding while storing data otherwise some word read would contain a portion of data. Ex. : (assume)if struct of three char (3 * 8 = 24 bits) and one int (16*1 = 16 bits) will be internally padded if word size is 32 bit, i.e. last 8 bits of first word will be empty.

Comment: this is low level compiler option that you don't have to care, but just remember that never believe that sum of sizeof data types in the struct is the size of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler stores the data of s[4] in linear memory, such as 10,20,15,25,8,75,6,2. i[7] is equal to 2.It is just a trick like the following example.

there is a structure like this:

```
struct block{
int a;
int b;
};

struct block item;
```

If I know the address of `item->b`, how can I know the address of `item`.

The answer is using the address of `item->b` minus `((struct block *)0)->b`.